# Pandas Resample Date Time Alignment

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to resample hourly data into 4-hour blocks but the resampled times and values are incorrect.

The resampled data should end at 17:00 UTC and start at 21:00 UTC for each day.
[image: correct_resample]

But the resampled data looks like this

[image: incorrect_resample]

I'm using the following code to resample

```
resampled_data = df.resample('4H').agg(ohlc)
```

Comment: You should [adjust the `loffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

Comment: Ok, it fixed the times but the resampled open value is incorrect. It should be the same as the daily open value = 2020-06-22 21:00:00  3123.5

Comment: The values are incorrect because on Friday 19/06 it should end the day at 17:00 and start again on Sunday 21/06 at 21:00 - https://imgur.com/jsDg5qg Do I need to use custom business hours or something?

Comment: closed='right' seems to have resolved it. thanks for assistance.